# Get the corresponding View for a type from Windsor

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have the following classes defined:

```
public interface IShapeView
{
    void DoSomethingWithShape(Shape shape);
}
public interface IShapeView<T> where T : Shape
{
    void DoSomethingWithShape(T shape);
}

public class CircleView : IShapeView<Circle>, IShapeView
{
    public void DoSomethingWithShape(Circle shape)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Circle:" + shape.Radius);
    }
    void IShapeView.DoSomethingWithShape(Shape shape)
    {
        DoSomethingWithShape((Circle)shape);
    }
}
public class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle()
    {
        Radius = 1.0;
    }

    public double Radius { get; set; }
}
```

And the following registration:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IShapeView<Circle>>().ImplementedBy<CircleView>());
```

Is there a method that I can call to resolve a view when I only have the Type of the shape?
Or do I need to go to the trouble of using reflection to create the generic type arguments to get the correct type of IShapeView that I want?  Looking for something like this:

```
Type shapeType = typeof(Circle);
IShapeView view = (IShapeView) container.SomeResolveMethod(shapeType, typeof(IShapeView<>));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no method built in because it's not needed. The reason why it's not needed is that in real application you never would pull the component directly from the container - you'd use a typed factory instead.

Typed factory can be easily taught to deal with this scenario. Have a look [at this post](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more.aspx).